# Invalid Request when calling my Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call my web api from a c# client app

This is my API Controller server code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Services.Customer> Get(Guid CompanyRef)
    {
        return customerRepository.Get(CompanyRef);
    }

    public Models.CustomerAddress Add(Guid CompanyRef, string ContactNo, Guid CustomerRef, string DOE, string Email, string FName, string SName,
        Guid? addressRef, string add1, string add2, string add3, string town, string county, string pCode, string country)
    {
        var res= customerRepository.Add(CompanyRef, ContactNo, CustomerRef, DOE, Email, FName, SName,
             addressRef,  add1,  add2,  add3,  town,  county,  pCode,  country);
        return new Models.CustomerAddress {
            AddressRef =res.AddressRef,
            CustomerRef =res.CustomerRef,
            CustomerExists=  (res.CustomerRef==CustomerRef)? true : false
        };
    }
```

by typing the uri directly into a browser I can test this.

```
http://myipaddress/api/Customer?CompanyRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000&ContactNo=contactno2&CustomerRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&DOE=doe2&Email=email2&FName=fname2&SName=sname2&AddressRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Add1=add1&Add2=add2&Add3=add3&Town=town&County=county&PCode=pcode&Country=country
```

but I get this response:

```
Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
</Error>
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong?

thanks

ADDITIONAL INFO

This is my code for calling it from a C# desktop client:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
    var response = client.PostAsync(route + "?" +
        GeneralTags.COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef + "&" +
        GeneralTags.CONTACT_NO + "=" + customer.ContactNo + "&" +
        GeneralTags.CUSTOMER_REF + "=" + customerLookUpResult.CustomerRef + "&" +
        GeneralTags.DOE + "=" + customer.DOE + "&" +
        GeneralTags.EMAIL + "=" + customer.Email + "&" +
        GeneralTags.FNAME + "=" + customer.FName + "&" +
        GeneralTags.SNAME + "=" + customer.SName + "&" +
        GeneralTags.ADDRESS_REF + "=" + addressLookUpResult.AddressRef +
        GeneralTags.ADD1 + "=" + customer.Add1 + "&" +
        GeneralTags.ADD2 + "=" + customer.Add2 + "&" +
        GeneralTags.ADD3 + "=" + customer.Add3 + "&" +
        GeneralTags.TOWN + "=" + customer.Town + "&" +
        GeneralTags.COUNTY + "=" + customer.County + "&" +
        GeneralTags.PCODE + "=" + customer.PCode + "&" +
        GeneralTags.COUNTRY + "=" + customer.Country
       , null).Result;

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var objs = JArray.Parse(json);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.CustomerAddress>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

When I use this it goes into my:

```
public IEnumerable<Services.Customer> Get(Guid CompanyRef)
```

MODIFIED URI:L

This is my uri:

```
"http://uri/api/Customer/Add?CompanyRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&ContactNo=contactno2&CustomerRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&DOE=doe2&Email=email2&FName=fname2&SName=sname2&AddressRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000Add1=add1&Add2=add2&Add3=add3&Town=town&County=county&PCode=pcode&Country=country"
```

Comment: What is the name of  your controller?

Comment: We debugging, does it hit the controller?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose it is: public class CustomerController : ApiController

Comment: @BillMartin Not from the browser but If I create a httpclient from a c# desktop it goes into  public IEnumerable<Services.Customer> Get(Guid CompanyRef) for some reason

Comment: You can use fiddler to inspect the data + URL that is generated by the desktop application

Comment: thanks.  I am trying Fiddler now

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a POST, but you're passing the values in the querystring, which is typically done for GET operations.  Perhaps you should try to POST the content in the body of the request instead of the URL.

Comment: @Matthew hi, thanks. Sort of makes sense to me.  May I ask for an example?

Comment: In your `PostAsync` call, instead of passing `null`, you would pass an `HttpContent` instance, take a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109246/post-json-httpcontent-to-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Your signature doesn't match the controller. The model binder is expecting a GUID but you're passing much more.

Pass this instead:
http://myipaddress/api/Customer?CompanyRef=(enter guid here)

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer. I have updated my answer. The variables I have passed in are GUIDs.. Perhaps testing via a browser was not such a great idea :)

Comment: Should work in a browser though. I'd recommend either Fiddler or Postman. Great for webapi work.

Comment: Hi Bill. Sorry if this is an inane question (been looking at this too long and way overdue a coffee) but the routing stuff which definitely looks cleaner... do I just use (in this case)  [Route("Customer/{Add}/{CustomerRef}/{ContactNo}/etc etc etc")]? thanks

Comment: It would be [Route("Customer/Add/{CustomerRef}/{ContactNo}/etc etc etc")]. Then your url would be http://service/customer/Add/(customerRef)/(CustomerNo).

Comment: If you are adding, you really should use a POST. Then call service/customer/Add and send data in the body. Create a model that matches your data and use this as your param : Add([FromBody] ModelWithData model)

Comment: hi, why 'service' (I have been playing around but not having much luck.Why am I so thick?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94621/discussion-between-bill-martin-and-andrew-simpson).

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you have a method called Add. This method is not decorated with the [HttpGet]. It looks like it is a POST method. You cannot call a POST method from the browser url in this way.

If you want it to be called add the attribute to the Add action

```
[HttpGet]
public Models.CustomerAddress Add(Guid CompanyRef, string ContactNo, Guid CustomerRef, string DOE, string Email, string FName, string SName,
    Guid? addressRef, string add1, string add2, string add3, string town, string county, string pCode, string country)
{
    var res= customerRepository.Add(CompanyRef, ContactNo, CustomerRef, DOE, Email, FName, SName,
         addressRef,  add1,  add2,  add3,  town,  county,  pCode,  country);
    return new Models.CustomerAddress {
        AddressRef =res.AddressRef,
        CustomerRef =res.CustomerRef,
        CustomerExists=  (res.CustomerRef==CustomerRef)? true : false
    };
}
```

Once you have done this, you will need to call it using the Url with the Add action specified

```
http://myipaddress/api/Customer/Add?CompanyRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000&ContactNo=contactno2&CustomerRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&DOE=doe2&Email=email2&FName=fname2&SName=sname2&AddressRef=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Add1=add1&Add2=add2&Add3=add3&Town=town&County=county&PCode=pcode&Country=country
```

If you need it to be a POST method, you could use POSTMAN to test your url.

Comment: If you're adding, wouldn't you want to decorate with HttpPost?

Comment: @BillMartin Yes it should. That's why the last line in the answer. Andrew was trying to test it through the browser, that is why the suggestion.

Comment: @BillMartin explains why is what was hanging for ages :)

Comment: @PraveenPaulose I have does as you suggested ie [httpPost] but it still calls my 'Get' api? :(

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I'd recommend using attribute routing. Makes sure the correct method gets called : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Are you testing it through the browser?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose hi, added httpPost and httpGet and it calls the Get API. (I added the uri to end of my question)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Remove the HttpPost attribute, keep the HttpGet attribute and test it.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose did that - thanks - took longer to get a reply but again same result.  I shall  look at the routing stuff Bill kindly sent me

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I recommend that too :)

Comment: @PraveenPaulose thanks for all your help.It was educational and I know a bit more now.  :)